# Bash: always display file possibilities on tab-complete

Tags: bash, tab-completion

When I use tab for filename completion and there are more than ~100 matches, it displays something like "Display all 403 possibilities? (y or n)". This gets annoying when I do it many times a day. Is there a way to always display all completions instead of this prompt? Or even better, set the threshold above which it displays the prompt?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can set the threshold by adding a line like this to your ~/.inputrc file:

```
set completion-query-items 1000
```

The default is 100 and 0 appears to set no limit. This is documented in the bash(1) man page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but what worked for me was to turn this readline option off in my `.bashrc`:

```
bind "set page-completions off"
```

which then make the tab show all options. As per the readline manpage:

> `page-completions` (`On`) 
> If set to `On`, readline uses an internal more-like pager to
> display a screenful of possible completions at a time.